# Layout change after screen resize CSS

Tags: css, resize

I have various errors with my design.

**First of all**, [here](http://ramroweb.com/mnml/) is the link to the example site that I have been doing to learn HTML and CSS.

http://ramroweb.com/mnml/style.css

When the screen size is resized all the items from container moves to the right. Even though I used `margin: 0 auto;`

The whole content is within the `div id="container"` but still it selects upto the `section tag` excluding `footer tag`.

The background image does not fit the whole size creating some `padding` on the `top`.

It would be great if I get help with these queries.

Thank you...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a responsive design try using percentages or vw/vh measurements. This way all the elements will get relative sizes to the user screen size. It's also good practice to make your website mobile accessible, so everything will nicely fit in the page when you open it on a narrower screen. More here -> https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units. For example, check out this code (obviously you might want to adjust the scaling to fit your needs):

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(img/beach.png) center no-repeat;
    background-color: #f3f2de;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 15%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
    color: #cc0000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 92%;
}

header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: solid 5% black;
}

nav {

}

nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10%;
    margin: 0 20%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10% 0;
}

a:link {

}

a:visited {
    color: #cc0000;
}

a:hover {
    color: #fff200;
}

section {
    margin: 30% 0 40%;
}

section h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1em;
}

section a {
    display: block;
    align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 30%;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body wrapper is at a fixed width.

```
body {
    width: 1020px;
}
```

You may switch that to 100% as you resize

```
@media all and (max-width: 1020px) {
    body {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

That should be a good lead to answer the *whats wrong*... Adjust the rest of your CSS as you see fit. Do edit the relevant code into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a min-width in the body

```
width: 100% !important;
min-width: 1000px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
```