# vertical progress bar on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a vertical progress bar that starts from the bottom as the user scrolls

I have found this example of a horizontal progress bar https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_indicator.asp

How would I make it run vertically?

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop;
var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - 
document.documentElement.clientHeight;
var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

Comment: Think of it this way: if you normally change `width` to move in the horizontal direction, what do you change to move in the vertical direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_scroll_indicator from your example then adding to `.progress-container`:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
-moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
-ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
transform-origin: 0 100%;
transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
```

would convert the progress bar from horizontal to vertical starting from bottom.

`rotate(90deg)` did the rotating trick, `scaleX(-1)` reverse the position 180 degree, `translate(-100%,-50%)` fix the position as it should be before reversed 180 degree.

See snippet for example:

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%,-50%);      
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
  <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
  <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

If you want to start from top vertically then you don't need to use `scaleX(-1)` and `translate(-100%,-50%)`

```js
// When the user scrolls the page, execute myFunction 
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  var winScroll = document.body.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  var scrolled = (winScroll / height) * 100;
  document.getElementById("myBar").style.width = scrolled + "%";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.header h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: 0 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);      
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  width: 0%;
}

.content {
  padding: 100px 0;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h2>Scroll Indicator</h2>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <div class="progress-bar" id="myBar"></div>
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="content">
  <h3>Scroll Down to See The Effect</h3>
  <p>We have created a "progress bar" to <b>show how far a page has been scrolled</b>.</p>
  <p>It also <b>works when you scroll back up</b>.</p>
  <p>It is even <b>responsive</b>! Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

Update as stated in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452819/vertical-progress-bar-on-scroll/54453033?noredirect=1#comment95718070_54453033):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var s = $(window).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(window).height();
  scrollPercent = (s / (d - c)) * 100;
  var position = scrollPercent;

  $("#progressbar").attr('value', position);

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

progress {
  background: #4caf50;
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: -40px;
  width: 50vw;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%, -50%);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%, -50%);
  -ms-transform-origin: 0 100%;
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%, -50%);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg) scaleX(-1) translate(-100%, -50%);
}

#top {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}


#middle {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

#centre {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}
#lower {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

#bottom {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #add8e6;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress id="progressbar" value="0" max="100"></progress>

<div id="top">
  <h1>top</h1>
</div>

<div id="middle">
  <h1>middle</h1>
</div>

<div id="centre">
  <h1>middle</h1>
</div>

<div id="lower">
  <h1>middle</h1>
</div>
 

<div id="bottom">
  <h1>bottom</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I would make the progress bar permanently fit the browser? currently it is running the whole length of the webpage

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you mean by progress bar permanently fit the browser?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? [bottom top](http://jsfiddle.net/scunv6yf/1/) [top bottom](http://jsfiddle.net/scunv6yf/2/)

Comment: Ok for example in this pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LqxWWw the progress bar moves out of screen as you scroll towards the bottom but I want it to start from the bottom and reach the top of the browser as you reach the bottom if that makes sense

Comment: Updated, works in full page. If you want to make it responsive you need to tweak it. See following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572947/layout-change-after-screen-resize-css). Or [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is replace width with height:

```
/* The progress container (grey background) */
.progress-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  background: #ccc;
}

/* The progress bar (scroll indicator) */
.progress-bar {
  width: 8px;
  background: #4caf50;
  height: 0%;
}
```

`document.getElementById("myBar").style.height = scrolled + "%";`

Now just place the progress bar next to the scroll container.